# d3 Sankey - Highlight all connected paths from start to end

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to highlight all the connected links and links of their target nodes till the end of the layout.

The first level of highlighting can be easily achieved as follows -

On node click, call `highlight_paths(1)`;

```
function highlight_paths(stroke_opacity) {
    return function(d,i){
        d.sourceLinks.forEach(function(srcLnk){
            d3.select("#link"+srcLnk.id).style("stroke-opacity", stroke_opacity);
        });
        d.targetLinks.forEach(function(srcLnk){
            d3.select("#link"+srcLnk.id).style("stroke-opacity", stroke_opacity);
        });
    }
}
```

But I'm not yet able to write correctly a recursive algorithm to get all the sourceLinks and targetLinks of each of the connected source & target nodes.

All thoughts are appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/9MMnwB5CoYc) should help.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff! This surely would've helped but I just found the solution so posting it here.

Comment: Thanks @milen-pavlov for the formatting! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was going through the sankey layout code and found a Breadth First Search implementation for traversing the layout nodes. Some knowledge on BFS here - [http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch14.html](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Egurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch14.html)

Purely based on that, here is the function to highlight all the paths from the clicked node in both the directions - Forward ( Target ) and Backward (Source)

Hope this helps someone!

Working examples -

http://bl.ocks.org/git-ashish/8959771

https://observablehq.com/@git-ashish/sankey-diagram

```
function highlight_node_links(node,i){

  var remainingNodes=[],
      nextNodes=[];

  var stroke_opacity = 0;
  if( d3.select(this).attr("data-clicked") == "1" ){
    d3.select(this).attr("data-clicked","0");
    stroke_opacity = 0.2;
  }else{
    d3.select(this).attr("data-clicked","1");
    stroke_opacity = 0.5;
  }

  var traverse = [{
                    linkType : "sourceLinks",
                    nodeType : "target"
                  },{
                    linkType : "targetLinks",
                    nodeType : "source"
                  }];

  traverse.forEach(function(step){
    node[step.linkType].forEach(function(link) {
      remainingNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
      highlight_link(link.id, stroke_opacity);
    });

    while (remainingNodes.length) {
      nextNodes = [];
      remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node[step.linkType].forEach(function(link) {
          nextNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
          highlight_link(link.id, stroke_opacity);
        });
      });
      remainingNodes = nextNodes;
    }
  });
}

function highlight_link(id,opacity){
    d3.select("#link-"+id).style("stroke-opacity", opacity);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful question, beautiful answer.

Comment: Really nice, but I have noticed that if you click a node, then the hover-highlighting seems broken. Click a node and then click again (to turn off the traverse). Then hover is not working for the edges that got highlighted. (Chrome, OSX)

Comment: @schnee Its fixed now. Same link. On hover, the link stroke-opacity is changed. But as the click highlighting applies stroke opacity at the element in-line level, the hover style was not getting applied. I've now made that ``!important`` so that it is always considered. Doing this via css is the way to go.

Comment: What is node[step.linkType]? step.linkType returns either "sourceLinks" or "targetLinks" but what is node[sourceLinks]? I keep getting "undefined" for that line of code.

Comment: @DaoLam consider "sourceLinks" or "targetLinks" like tree branches which give you nodes for sources and targets of the clicked node respectively. If you can point us to a fiddle, that would be good. Otherwise, I assume "node" in your case is not pointing to the proper dataset / datum.

Comment: Does this demo actually function with complete highlighting of paths? I am **not** seeing full path highlighting in the demo block. It seems like the click event is not firing at all. https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2488

Comment: @mg1075 Update the demo. Works now.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because it's highlighting all connections of the next level in the flow, rather than just the nodes and links that are truly connected to the source.

Comment: @kimli highlighting all the connections is what was needed not just the immediate neighbours

Comment: Any working example from a notebook Observable ?

Comment: Starting from https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram

Comment: @pbrockmann https://observablehq.com/@git-ashish/sankey-diagram. Things remain same.

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@pbrockmann/sankey-diagram-with-highlighted-path
Ok get my notebook working. Many thanks @AshishSingh
Some changes to better fit my purpose.