# r sankeyNetwork Highlight all connecting paths of a node

Tags: r, d3.js, sankey-diagram

is there a solution to hilite the whole path of a node in R sankeyNetwork plot?

you can see a working example here:
https://setsna2.shinyapps.io/sankey-shinyforallcities/

click for example the node Leadship&Strategy you will see that the path left and right will be highlited. I would like to do this in R Shiny, is there a possibility to do the same hiliting in R with the sankeyNetwork plot?

When I do this, it does not work

```
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
      'master/JSONdata/energy.json');energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL);sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
     Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
     units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Comment: Maybe with the `googleVis` package you can do it.

Comment: i would like to solve it in Shiny, the googleVis function works in the browser and the hilite function is not hiliting the whole path

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142160/highlight-all-connected-paths-from-start-to-end-in-sankey-graph-using-r